# Rails: submit Ajax form via anchor click

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm porting an existing app to rails that makes extensive use of stylized anchors for form submission:

```
   <a class="lozenge-button h25 blue" href="#">
      <span class="left"></span>
      <span class="center">Send</span>
      <span class="right"></span>
   </a>
```

However in Rails these anchors won't work for Ajax form submission, since Rails' UJS seems to require an input tag rather than an anchor (i.e. `submit_tag("Submit", remote: true)`).

Is there a way to make my anchors fire the Ajax form submission? I managed to get the anchor to submit the form with the following:

```
$('#my_anchor').click(function() { $(this).closest('form').submit();});
```

... but it bypasses Ajax and does a normal form submit that reloads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it in a way very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414549/93995):

```
<%= f.submit id: 'hidden_submit_button', style: 'display: none;' %>

<a class="lozenge-button h25 blue" href="#" onclick="$('#hidden_submit_button').click(); return false;">
    <span class="left"></span>
    <span class="center">Send</span>
    <span class="right"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize());
```

Comment: When I try that my controller action fires, but with format.html rather than format.js, and then it can't find the template (the form itself is rendered via a .js template).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you add remote:true to your link helper method. Then rails_ujs, (Rails unobtrusive javascript) takes care of sending it via ajax. See [The Rails Ajax Guide](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) so your code would become (in ERB)

```
<%= link_to the_rails_path,remote:true,class:"lozenge-button h25 blue" do %>
 <span>etc</span>
 <span>etc</span>
<%end%>
```