# Setting the global ajax datatype breaks rails remote links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, coffeescript

I have created a rails application that submits a form remotely and then displays form validation errors if validation does not pass.

My form works perfectly. I have however found that the way I set it up, breaks any remote links. The reason for this is that I setup the global AJAX dataType to be 'json'. If I remove this setting, my remote links work, but then my form 'success' and 'failure events aren't triggered.

Here is my code...

## application.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

## foo.coffee

```
$('#foo_form').on('ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  console.log 'Great success'
).on 'ajax:error', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
  console.log('Great Failure')
```

## index.haml

```
= link_to "New Foo",new_foo_path, data: { remote: true}
```

To summarise: Using the code above allows me to submit forms remotely, after which either the success or error message is logged to my console. The remote link however, does not work with the '$.ajaxSetup({dataType: 'json'})' setting defined above. If I remove this piece of code, the links work, but then the form events aren't triggered.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried:

`= link_to "New Foo", new_foo_path(format: :json), data: {remote: true}`

Please describe what is not working with remote links exactly? 500, 404, not preventedDefault by javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit your form, not have a link that points to the action.  If you want your form data to be submitted, use a `form_for` or `form_tag` and `.submit` or `submit_tag` view helper.

```
= form_tag (new_foo_path, remote: true) do
  = submit_tag("New Foo")
```

A `link_to` will create an anchor tag which will not know about your form data.  If you want to stylize the form button as a link:

```
= submit_tag("submit", style: 'display: none;', id: 'submit_foo')
= link_to( "New Foo", "#", :onClick => "$('#submit_foo').click(); return false;" )
```

[submit ajax form with link (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414284/rails-3-1-submit-an-ajax-remote-true-form-with-a-link/10414549#10414549)